# Not able to access a File Resource using Spring 3.x

Tags: spring

I have been trying to open this .json file for a while and it giving me a null pointer exception. Please let me know if I am doing something incorrect.

```
/**
 * Handles requests for the application UI.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/UIController")
public class UIController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UIController.class);
private @Autowired ServletContext servletContext;

@RequestMapping(value = "/ClientTree", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String clientTree() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("C:\\ClientJson.json");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        return bufferedReader.readLine();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
           inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to open and read the file contents, sending those contents to the UI to populate a tree jQuery widget.

Comment: could you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: Just got it working, i had to give it a /resource/ based path.